# How do I make my Sprite appear in my window?

Tags: python, pygame

I have made an enemy sprite within my game, however it is not displayed on the screen. I am wondering how I would be able to make it appear?

Tried updating the pygame display in the class but it still won't show the image. I plan on making the sprite appear in order to allow it to move to the end of the grid line (horizontally), then shift down vertically when it reaches the end of a horizontal point.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((650, 630))

pygame.display.set_caption("PeaShooters")

avatar = pygame.image.load('Sprite 1 Red.png')
background = pygame.image.load('Bg.jpg')
white = (255, 255, 255)

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, shots):
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 500
        self.width = 40
        self.height = 60
        self.vel = shots



def drawGrid():
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    window.blit(avatar, (av.x, av.y))
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [50, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [600,600], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,600], [600, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,450], [600, 450], 5)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()


class shots(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, colour):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.colour = colour
        self.vel = shots

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.colour, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

class enemy(object):
    enemy = pygame.image.load('Sprite 3 Red.png')
    pygame.display.update()

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self. x, self.end]
        self.vel = 4

    def draw(self,window):
        self.move()
        pass

    def move(self):
        pass

av = player(300, 500, 40, 60, 9)
bullets = []
running = True
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y < 600 and bullet.y > 70:
            bullet.y -= 8
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and av.y > 440:
        av.y -= av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and av.x > 65:
        av.x -= av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and av.y < 535:
        av.y += av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and av.x < 530:
        av.x += av.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(shots(round(av.x + av.width//2), round(av.y + av.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))


    drawGrid()

window.blit(avatar, (x,y))

pygame.quit()
```

I expect the avatar to appear on the screen so I can allow it to move.

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is right? this line`window.blit(avatar, (x,y))` should be in your While loop but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Where in the while loop?

Comment: Just after `drawGrid()`. Where it would be now if you just indent it to the same level of the previous line.

Comment: Alright, how about the enemy problem as I am struggling to make them appear.

Answer (score 1):

All drawing should be done in the while loop. Or you call directly the `window.blit` function on the various sprites, or you wrap it in a sprite method which is called during the loop (I see you have a `draw()` method but right now it does nothing). Choose one way and follow that. I personally prefer the second one, it's more object oriented, but it is my opinion.
And remember to clear the previous position if you want to give a sense of motion.
`display.update()` should be called once per iteration, usually at the end, after all the sprites have been blit.

Your enemy does not appear because you never blit it's image. Actually, you never create an enemy, you have defined the class only.
So first create an enemy adding a line such that `en = enemy(ex, ey, w, h, end)`. `ex` and `ey` here should be the position of the enemy on the screen, choose what you prefer. `w` and `h` the width and height of the image. `end` I do not know (your class, you added it, you should know what is its purpose). You can add this line just after you create the `avatar`.
Then remove the `display.update()` from the class, and add a call `window.blit(en, (en.x, en.y))` in the while loop. Or in `drawGrid()`, which actually is drawing everithing and not the grid only.

To move the enemy, you should edit its position (`en.x` and `en.y`) in the while loop as you do for the avatar, but not in response to a key press. Just set some sort of path. At each iteration, the enemy coordinates should change to follow this path, something like `en.x += en.vel` or whatever. The real path may be more complex, but this is up to you. The logic is: change the enemy coordinate each iteration of the loop.